# SkuDetails is not updated on price change

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, inappbrowser, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am facing an issue. I have implemented in-app billing by Google for android application and whenever I update a price of an in-app product, it is reflected in the in-app billing screen when `billingClient.launchBillingFlow()` is triggered. But I am also using the SkuDetails fetch callbacks to show real time pricing. It is still receiving the old pricing.

I am fetching skudetails like below.

```
billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParams) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
        if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.isNotEmpty()) {
            OnSkuDetailsFetchListener.onSkuDetailsFetchSuccessful(skuDetailsList[0])
        } else {
            OnSkuDetailsFetchListener.onSkuDetailsFetchFailure()
        }
    }
```

received SkuDetails is having the old price and hence I end up showing old price on my own applications' UI but when user clicks on the buy button, google's UI shows updated pricing.

How to fix it? This is definitely not the right experience for users.
Note: SkuDetails was never updated even when app data was cleared / app was reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

When you query for the user inventory with the billing API, you initiate the flow with launchPriceChangeConfirmationFlow().

Comment: I assume launchPriceChangeConfirmationFlow is for subscription only. The question is only about one time purchase items.